# AngularJs, ng-options and default option showing blank

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a ng-options, an array and a default ng-options-model of 0, ie the first element in the array. Why is the first name in the array shown in the dropdown (it is only blank)?

See [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/l4dKAS?p=preview).

I have this html:

```
<form>
  <select ng-options="index as contact.name for (index,contact) in contacts" ng-model="selectedContact"></select>
</form>
Selected contact array index (default 0): {{selectedContact}}
```

And this controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.contacts = [
    {email: "me@example.com", name: "Mini Me"},
    {email: "you@example.com", name: "Maxi You"}
  ];
  $scope.selectedContact = 0;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ng-options` syntax is a bit wrong, you're using the syntax for iterating an objects properties, when you actually have an array of objects:

```
ng-options="contact as contact.name for contact in contacts"
```

And then you set the index of the array to select the first one:

```
$scope.selectedContact = $scope.contacts[0];
```

Comment: The name is actually not unique. I have seen this way of iteration over an array for the reason of using the array index for the selected option...

Comment: @EricC - You should be using the above syntax, use `$index` to grab the index from the above syntax - then setting it as an actual number will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution myself. ng-repeat has the index as a string (so selectedContact is a string), but my controller was using a number. When I change my controller to:

```
$scope.selectedContact = "0";
```

Then it worked perfectly.